# I want to bind the entire column of the datatable to the gridviews dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

i am having gridview with ddl in a column, i have binded the entire list of skills to them form master table but while filling the form candidate have entered 2 skills those to skills should be binded as the SelectedValue in two ddl with the remaining list of items. I am not able to get the datable value in ddl's selected text

Answer (score 0):

please write with better readability, give some code if neccesary so some one can understand what you want to do,

there are millions of functionalities and thousands of way to do it

to answer to your question

```
    Gridview1.DataSource=dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);
    DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Name", "Id");
    DataRow[] dr=dt.Select(" UserID=5");
    dt=dr.CopyToDataTable();
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);
    DataTable distinctValues1 = view.ToTable(true, "Name", "Id");
    for(i=0;i<Gridview1.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
    DropDownList ddl1=((DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].FindControl("ddl1"));
    ddl1.DataTextField="Name";
    ddl1.DataValueField="Id";
    ddl1.DataSource=distinctValues ;
    ddl1.DataBind();

    DropDownList ddl2=((DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].FindControl("ddl2"));
    ddl2.DataTextField="Name";
    ddl2.DataValueField="Id";
    ddl2.DataSource=distinctValues1 ;
    ddl2.DataBind();


    DropDownList ddl3=((DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].FindControl("ddl3"));
    ddl3.DataTextField="Name";
    ddl3.DataValueField="Id";
    ddl3.DataSource=distinctValues1 ;
    ddl3.DataBind();

    }
```

it wold be prefered if you managed to take dropdowns data in saperate datatable, it will reduce your space complexity your master table is containing